# Creart Gazebo World based on map

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I have the map data (pgm , yaml) created by a laser scan, now I am wondering if I can use this map data to creat a Gazebo Environment (World), I know I can edit an environment in Gazebo and save it as (config and sdf), but I must do it manually, is there an easier way to do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356033/creart-gazebo-world-based-on-map/) by [binzhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/55053/binzhou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out this package:

https://github.com/shilohc/map2gazebo

It claims to do exactly what you are asking for.  See also this discussion on ROS Discourse:

https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-package-convert-2d-maps-to-gazebo-worlds/14528

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2020-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [binzhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/55053/binzhou/) on 2020-06-29**:
Thank you, it seems exactly what I need, I  will try it now, thank you very much.